# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bindValue() in

Tags: php

i'm trying to fetch data from the database but i'm getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bindValue() in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\article.php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\article.php(11): Article->fetch_data('0') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\article.php on line 17

C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\article.php

```
<?php
class Article {

    public  function fetch_all(){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }

    public function fetch_data($article_id){
        global $pdo;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ? ");
        $query = bindValue(1, $article_id);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    } 
}
?>
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\article.php

```
<?php

include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;


if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $data = $article->fetch_data($id);

    print_r($data);
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$query = bindValue(1, $article_id);
```

to this

```
$query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
```

`bindValue` is a method of PDOStatement, not a separate function
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: typo's shouldn't be answered but closed IMO

Comment: it wasn't a typo it was a misunderstanding

Comment: @delboy1978uk it's under the same grounds (as in, not beneficial to future users)

Comment: it would be if they thought bindValue was a plain PHP function? Anyway. Have a good day!

Comment: *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Answer (score 1):

`bindValue()` is a method of the PDOStatement object, which is returned by the prepare call. You want something like this:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?');
$query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
$query->execute();
```

You can also use named parameters:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = :article_id');
$query->bindValue('article_id', $article_id);
$query->execute();
```

Also, don't rely on global variables, it breaks the basic concepts of object-oriented programming. Instead, pass the PDO connection object as a parameter into the Article object. This is called [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

```
class Article
{
    protected $pdo;
    public function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }
    public function fetch_all() {
        $query = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Then just pass `$pdo` as a parameter when you instantiate an Article:

```
$article = new Article($pdo);
```

Comment: typo's shouldn't be answered but closed IMO